# Php through How to check uploaded zip or rar file is password protected or not

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

I just need to check uploaded zip or rar file is password protected or not.

Through php how can we check this?

I only need message that file is password protected when upload.

Thanks,

hello , thanks for your replay and help. but every time $var_val[0] have 0(No Password) value if password protected or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Of course your server needs 7z and unrar installed.  But I assume you do since you are dealing with these types.  Since the actual shell commands depend on your server OS you may need to edit.

here is 7zip:

```
$zipfile = './uploaded.zip';
$zip_cmd = '7za l -slt -- '.$zipfile.' | grep -i -c "Encrypted = +"';
exec($zip_cmd, $zip_val);

if($zip_val[0] == 1) {
        echo "Password protected\n";
} else {
        echo "No password\n";
}
```

Here is unrar:

```
$rarfile = './uploaded.rar';
$rar_cmd = 'unrar x -p- -y -o+ '.$rarfile.' 2> /dev/null | grep -i -c "$Total errors: .*$"';
exec($rar_cmd, $rar_val);

if($rar_val[0] == 1) {
        echo "Password protected\n";
} else {
        echo "No password\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay,
    I dont want to change name of file. i just want to given error message when zip with password protected and upload.
so i did this code. can you please help me how can i check in this 
    if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path)) {
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
     $x = $zip->open($target_path);
     if ($x === true) {
     $zip->extractTo("/var/www/mayur/ziprar/"); 
     $zip->close();
     unlink($target_path);
     }
Thanks again

Comment: Thanks ,but not understand how to write this in PHP ?

Comment: @user3114036, please add the code to your question, not in comments to answers.

Comment: hello , thanks for your replay and help.  but every time $var_val[0] have 0(No Password) value if password protected or not. Thanks.

Comment: Try testing on the command line.  Remove the grep parts if you aren't seeing anything.  This is really dependent on the OS and install options used while installing unrar, rar, and 7zip.  Also, try a var_dump on the $zip_val and $rar_val arrays to see what the script is getting.

Comment: thanks you. if i print $zip_val it will return Array([0]=>0) every time if password or not.